# how do i select an image as an url from my map called img?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a memory game with cards. And one of the things i have to do is select an image from an map called img and write it as a url.

Also i don't know if my code is correct, this is what i tried:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cardgame</title>
    <link href="css/game.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="field"><img src="../begin/img/calf.jpg" alt="" name="calf">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
        <img src="../begin/img/cat.jpg" alt="" name="cat">
        <img src="../begin/img/chick.jpg" alt="" name="chick">
        <img src="../begin/img/cow.jpg" alt="" name="cow">
        <img src="../begin/img/dog.jpg" alt="" name="dog">
        <img src="../begin/img/duck.jpg" alt="" name="duck">
        <img src="../begin/img/goat.jpg" alt="" name="goat">
        <img src="../begin/img/goose.jpg" alt="" name="goose">
        <img src="../begin/img/hen.jpg" alt="" name="hen">
        <img src="../begin/img/horse.jpg" alt="" name="horse">
        <img src="../begin/img/kitten.jpg" alt="" name="kitten">
        <img src="../begin/img/lamb.jpg" alt="" name="lamb">
        <img src="../begin/img/pig.jpg" alt="" name="pig">
        <img src="../begin/img/piglet.jpg" alt="" name="piglet">
        <img src="../begin/img/puppy.jpg" alt="" name="puppy">
        <img src="../begin/img/rooster.jpg" alt="" name="rooster">
        <img src="../begin/img/sheep.jpg" alt="" name="sheep">
        <img src="../begin/img/veal.jpg" alt="" name="veal">
    </div>

    <script src="js/memory.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
"use strict";

const myCardSet = ["duck", "kitten", "piglet", "puppy", "calf", "veal", "lamb", "rooster", "horse", "mouse", "dog", "cat", "goose", "goat", "sheep", "pig", "cow", "chick", "hen"];

document.addEventListener('onload', function () {
    populatieField()
})

class card {
    constructor(card1) {
        this.card1 = myCardSet[0]
    }
}
function populateField() {
    for (let i = 0; i < myCardSet.length; i++) {
        let newTile = document.createElement('div');
        let newCard = document.createElement('img');
        let imageURL = 'img' + card.card1 + '.jpg'
        newCard.setAttribute('src', imageURL)
        newCard.setAttribute('name', imageURL)
        newTile.appendChild(newCard)
        myField.appendChild(newTile)
    }
}
const myField = document.getElementById('field').addEventListener('click', function onClickCard(e) {
    this.getAttribute(e.target.name)
    console.log(e.target.name)
}
)



function shuffle(arr) {
    var i = arr.length, j, temp;
    while (--i > 0) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i]
        arr[i] = temp
    }
}

shuffle(myCardSet)
populateField()
```

I keep getting the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
at populateField

Please help me, thanks already!

Comment: `addEventListener` has undefined as return value, and that is what you assigned to  `myField`. Make that `const myField = document.getElementById('field'); myField.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: you are not storing 'myField' properly, addEventListener returns undefined (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: thanks for the answers, is the rest of the code good for the memory game? what should i add more to the code?

Comment: how do i add the images from my html to the class card and to imageURL?